# What model for the chat messages classification should I use?

Tags: classification, natural-language

I need to classify chat messages into 10 classes. For example, if I recieve message "Do you give loans?" or "Can you give me money", model should classify it as "loan". I also need to recognize messages as "I not need your money" ("denial" will also be a class) or messages with rude words. Which model or algorithm  should I choose and what size do I need of dataset?